# How can I squash all commits into newly created branch

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

I need to create new branch (let's call it 'TestBranch') with current master code. I want to see just one squashed commit, like "Master Commit #1" which will contain all previous commits with master. Right now I have a ton of small commits in my test branch.

I've tried to run this:

1. git rev-list --count HEAD (to understand how much commits are in master)
2. git rebase -i HEAD~NUMBER_OF_COMMITS

but with no success, because I get some merge conflicts, but I do not understand how can I get merge conflicts in this situation.

How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I do the followings to squash:

```
# to squash previous 3 commits
$ git reset --soft HEAD~3

$ git add --all; git commit -m 'new message'

# force push is required
$ git push -f origin <branch-name>
```

Comment: After git rev-list --count HEAD I get X commits. 
I run git reset --soft HEAD~3 and got exception:

fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD~X': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

Comment: let me generate your situation

Comment: Have you checked `$ git log` and its output?

Comment: Please see this, https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/44776#issuecomment-378942407 for the reason.